# object of class without parameterless constructor in automated storage and exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, c++17

I have a factory method that returns object of a class type.

```
MyClass factory(string param1, ...) {
  ...
  MyClass instance(param1);
  ...
  if (smth) throw ...;
  ...
  return instance;
}
```

The factory method may throw.

I'm trying to create an object of this class with exception handling. Something like this:

```
MyClass obj;
try {
   obj = factory(...);
} catch (...) {
   cout << "oops..." << endl;
}
```

The problem, of course, that this does not work as `MyClass obj` creates instance, but I would like to avoid creating instance because it is time and resource consuming.

Probably I can change the return type of `factory` to `MyClass*` but then I need to face `new` and `delete`.

Is there a way to do it without `new` and creating a temporary instance but with exception handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (since C++17).

(emphasis mine)

> The class template `std::optional` manages an optional contained
>   value, ...
>
> If an `optional<T>` contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be
>   allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. **no dynamic
>   memory allocation ever takes place. Thus, an optional object models an
>   object, not a pointer**, even though operator*() and operator->() are
>   defined.

e.g.

```
std::optional<MyClass> obj;
try {
   obj = factory(...);
} catch (...) {
   cout << "oops..." << endl;
}
```

BTW: If you just don't want to handle `new` and `delete` manually, [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) is a nice choice too.

Comment: Thank you very much. optional looks exactly like what I need.

Comment: Seems `std::optional<MyClass> factory(...)` would make sense. (or `std::variant<MyClass, Error> factory(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
try {
   MyClass obj = factory(...);
   DoJob(obj);
} catch (...) {
   cout << "oops..." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to separate concerns - I do not expect exceptions from DoJob so would like it out of the factory exceptions.